Get telegram channel id using telethon in python
How to get the channel id of that has sent the message on telegram using telethon python
Below is the code that can receive messages from telegram
but How can I get the channel id from telethon
TELEGRAM_API_ID = xxx
TELEGRAM_API_HASH = "xxx"
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = "xxxxxx" 
TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME="bot_name"
client = TelegramClient(TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME, api_id=TELEGRAM_API_ID, api_hash=TELEGRAM_API_HASH)
client.start()


@client.on(events.NewMessage()) 
async def handler(event):
   raw_text=event.text
   channel_id=.... #how to get the channnel_id
   
   print("RAW_TEXT",raw_text,"CHANNEL_ID",channel_id)
   
client.run_until_disconnected()

Be able to get the channel id

The event you get from NewMessage has that data available in chat_id,
so you'll need
channel_id = event.chat_id


Thank you Ostone0 it worked. I also figured this as well                                          channel_id=chat_id=(1000000000000+int(event.message.peer_id.channel_id))*-1
